# how to create password field and button in vc++

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, button, passwords

I am new in vc++ and i need a `Password field` in my application. I created edit textbox using below code but don't know how to create password field and button control.

```
CreateWindow(L"EDIT", L"hello", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | ES_LEFT |
ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_WANTRETURN, 350, 500, 130, 20, hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Any help would be grateful. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try ES_PASSWORD :

> Displays an asterisk (*) for each
>   character typed into the edit control.
>   This style is valid only for
>   single-line edit controls.
>
> Windows XP: If the edit control is
>   from user32.dll, the default password
>   character is an asterisk. However, if
>   the edit control is from comctl32.dll
>   version 6, the default character is a
>   black circle.
>
> To change the characters that is
>   displayed, or set or clear this style,
>   use the EM_SETPASSWORDCHAR message.
>
> Note  Comctl32.dll version 6 is not
>   redistributable but it is included in
>   Windows XP or later. To use
>   Comctl32.dll version 6, specify it in
>   a manifest. For more information on
>   manifests, see Enabling Visual Styles.

Source : [Edit Control Styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775464%28VS.85%29.aspx)

**Edit**

You mean creating a button ? Via [Using Buttons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775949%28VS.85%29.aspx) :

```
     HWND hwndButton = CreateWindow( 
        L"BUTTON",   // Predefined class; Unicode assumed. 
        L"OK",       // Button text. 
        WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON, 
        0,         // x position. 
        0,         // y position. 
        50,        // Button width.
        50,        // Button height.
        hwnd_parentwindow,
        NULL,       // No menu.
        (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hwnd_parentwindow, GWL_HINSTANCE), 
        NULL);
```

Comment: thanks your applied your suggestion and its working. but answer is incomplete. How I can create button I mean string for creating button.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the edit box and right click and choose its properties. In that there is an option called password. Just check it.
Also this link will help you.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3223ht2.aspx
Or if you want you can directly add

> ES_PASSWORD

also along with rest.

Comment: The link you posted is for WinForms, not the Visual C++ dialog editor.